# Can I initialize Smarty elsewere and not in Bootstrap?

Tags: php, zend-framework, smarty

I implemented smarty on my Zend Framework project. I did it by folowing this tutorial [*Smarty 3 extension for Zend Framework*](http://gediminasm.org/article/smarty-3-extension-for-zend-framework). My problem is that a don't won't to initialize smarty for every module, so I need to know the name of the module before initialize Smarty in Bootstrap.

the following call wont work because `getRequest()` does not exist at the time:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getModuleName()
```

I know that I can get module name from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, but I don't like this solution.

Is there is another way to get module name or can I initialize Smarty elsewhere and not in `Bootstrap`? Maybe in `dispatchLoopStartup()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a controller plugin and initialize Smarty when `preDispatch` is fired:

```php
class App_Controller_Plugin_Smarty extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        if ('mymodule' === $request->getModuleName()) {
            // Initialize Smarty
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```